# underline certain words using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following:

**HTML:**

```
<span id="plus-shipping">+ Shipping</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
span#plus-shipping {
    bottom: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

How can i set the underline so its just the shipping and not the +

Answer (score 7):

The easiest option would be to wrap the 'shipping' string in another tag, such as `span` and apply the underline to that `span` only:

```
#plus-shipping > span {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

<span id="plus-shipping">+ <span>Shipping</span></span>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5vEFF/).

I also tried to use CSS-generated content `::before` to generate the `+` character, unfortunately (at least in Chrome 18/Win XP) this inherited the underline from its 'parent' `#plus-shipping` element, even if `text-decoration: none` was explicitly declared.

Comment: The underline isn't inherited. The problem is that the `::before` element actually lies _inside_ the span, so the span's underline expands to go underneath it.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, I hadn't thought of it that way (though it does make more sense than my own -lamentable- conclusion)

Comment: cant as `+ Shipping` is going to be a locale string resource. Just makes it easier for the user to have 1 resource to edit.

Comment: I'm clearly missing something, but...why does its being a 'locale string resource' prevent you from inserting that text into a specific `span` or, as in [Tats_innit's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10930537/82548), wrapping a `span` *around* that text string?

Answer (score 3):

**working demo** bit different : http://jsfiddle.net/d74Tn/ & another demo from David reside here: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d74Tn/1/

Can use `replace` API and then add `text-decoration: underline`

I hope it will help you.

**code**

```
var $el = $('#plus-shipping');
 $el.html( $el.html().replace(/Shipping/g, '<span style="text-decoration: underline">Shipping</span>') );
​
```

Comment: A minor suggestion, for brevity you don't need to write out the matched group, you could just use: `.replace(/Shipping/g, '<span style="text-decoration: underline">$&</span>')` [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d74Tn/1/).

Comment: @DavidThomas thank-you david changing it now, cheers bruv! B-)